# How Can I Create a Private OpenBSD Mirror?

Tags: openbsd, mirror

How can I create a private OpenBSD mirror. I'd like my mirror to have all the packages of the latest release for my preferred architectures (amd64 and i386) and everything else contained in a typical public mirror.

Is there a preferred method or tool to create a mirror? Are there any considerations one should have before creating a private mirror (other than having the courtesy to throttle downloading)?

Comment: You could just rsync from a public mirror.

Answer (score 6):

Per [OpenBSD's documentation for prospective public mirrors](http://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html#prospective), the recommended approach would be to use `rsync -rv --delete-delay --delay-updates --fuzzy $SOURCE_MIRROR $YOUR_MIRROR`, where `$SOURCE_MIRROR` is your chosen mirror (or perhaps a subdirectory thereof) and `$YOUR_MIRROR` is the mirror which you're creating.

There's generally not much to consider if you're just downloading files.  If you're the only one using this mirror and it's just to get everything pre-downloaded, then you might even opt to tweak the `rsync` command above to only fetch the directories in which you're interested (for example, only for your preferred architectures).  If you plan on making it available via HTTP (whether for yourself or for friends/coworkers/family/public/etc.), there's a [sample `/etc/httpd.conf`](http://www.openbsd.org/httpd.conf) available to accomplish precisely that.